# OnResponse Callback Not trigger

Tags: android, json, retrofit

in retrofit Client When Create data OnResponse Not Call
but Passing In the database
I cant intern in Another Activity.

```
public void saveUser(StudentName studentName){
    Call<StudentName>call =ApiClient.getStudentName().sendStudentName(studentName);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<StudentName>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<StudentName> call, Response<StudentName> response) {

            Intent  intent  = new Intent(StudentData.this,MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);


        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<StudentName> call, Throwable t) {



        }
    });
```

Comment: Have you checked the possibility that the response is called in `onFailure` ?

Comment: Yes,response is called in onFailure

Comment: So what is the question, you have some error in your request

Comment: but my data send in database

Comment: i Cant't show any error in request

Comment: You need to share more code, it seems like you have some problems with the logic flow